# Automatically renaming duplicate filenames in Windows 7 when copying to a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer

Is there a way of automatically renaming duplicate filenames in Windows 7 when copying to a folder? The only two options that show are effectively cancel copy and overwrite, which is infinitely annoying when you don't care about the filename so long as it's unique.

Comment: There *should* be a third option - "Copy, but keep both files", which will rename the file you are copying and keep the existing one.

Comment: only when bulk copying. When single copying, no such option appears.

Comment: I see it when copying single files as well.

Comment: I don't. There's likely a reg setting for it then, but who knows where?